# loading failed for Google Analyctics tracking scripts

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement the script's for Google Analyctics tracking, but I only get

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx”

Code;

```
<script async="async" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-13086351-3');
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see with the code is async="async". Try using the below code.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-13086351-3"></script>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-13086351-3');
</script>
```

---

Comment: `async=async` is valid HTML5.

Comment: I guess async="async" is XHTML attribute while async is the HTML attribute.

Comment: @AnujBansal it works now. after some research it turned out it got blocked by adblocker. turned off addblocker and it worked :)

Comment: That's great. But the problem here would be that some of your users would also have adblocker enabled and if the script fails to load for them, then you won't be able to capture their data. You should put some workaround method here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **framework** like **symfony**, there are some CSP (Content Security Policy) rules that may be in place.
It is necessary to **add in the configuration file** the url of the script which is called otherwise symfony refuses to load the script.

Also note, maybe that before you loaded an analytics script from **google-analytics.com** and now you loaded from **googletagmanager.com**

Config file in app (example for Symfony) :

```
csp:
  enabled: true
  enforce:
    script-src: // valid source of javascript
      - '*.googletagmanager.com'
```

Documentation :
https://content-security-policy.com/

*Using CSP rules is one of the best things to improve the security of your websites. they can block the use of third-party javascript to steal user passwords for example*.